# Delay of update Feature Management Integer parameter from subscriber org to LMO

Tags: feature-management

I have **integer feature management parameter** (IFMP) of type **Subscriber to LMO**.
I have code which updates IFMP in subscriber org where is installed managed package (2GP) but new value is updated in LMO after couple of hours.

1. Do you have the same experience?
2. Is there any way to speed up updates from subscriber org to LMO?
3. What approach do you use for fast updates of feature parameters from subscriber org to LMO?

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/fma_considerations.htm).

> When the Apex code in your package updates subscriber-to-LMO values in your subscriber’s org, the changes can take up to 24 hours to reach your LMO.

This is normal, expected, and documented behavior. You should not be constantly updating the value, it is intended to be used infrequently to collect, for example, aggregate data usage metrics.

You cannot make this feature work any faster than it is designed to. If you need more frequent or timely updates, consider making API calls from your package to a central location.

Comment: On the other hand documentation says: Create subscriber-to-LMO feature parameters to manage activation metrics. Set these feature parameters’ values in subscriber orgs using the Apex code in your managed package. For example, use subscriber-to-LMO feature parameters to track the number of e-signatures consumed ... So if I want to track the number of e-signatures consumed then I supposed that I could see them in LMO earlier because for example I want to make some action immediatally once some limit is reached.